# losing escape characters passing a path in json from Xamarin Forms c# to javascript

Tags: javascript, json, forms, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Forms app that is calling javascript and sending as a parameter a JSON string that contains a path.  When it leaves c# the back slashes have been double-escaped like this:

```
"myreturnfunc('', '{\"statusCode\":\"200\",\"path\":\"\\\\temp\\\\Uploads\\\\100650\\\\IMG_20200107_094705_5.jpg\"}');"
```

but when it gets into myreturnfunc only single back slashes remain:

```
"{"statusCode":"200","path":"\temp\Uploads\100650\IMG_20200107_094705_5.jpg"}"
```

which fails on JSON.parse.  What do I need to do to allow the escaped \'s to come through?  I call this method from another javascript function as well, and when called from there it comes through in the correct format:
"`{"path":"\\temp\\Uploads\\100650\\IMG_20200107_094705_5.jpg","statusCode":"200"}"`

Comment: It's not a particularly clean solution but if double escaping isn't enough you could try triple escaping. Have you tried escaping it once more before it leaves C#? Not sure how you'd do it in C# but in javascript you'd do something like `str.replace(/\\{2}/g, '\\'.repeat(4));` (replace each pair of backslashes with four backslashes).

Answer (score 0):

`Json.parse` typically encounters two escapes when the `json.parse` parameter contains the transition characters, the first being the escape of the string itself and the second being the escape of the actual js object.

for example,your string `\"path\":\"\\\\temp\\\\Uploads\\\\100650\\\\IMG_20200107_094705_5.jpg\"` above

First parser extracted strings think first `\` escape the second `\` and the third `\` escape the fourth `\`, that is to say, the actual output string is `"path":"\\temp\\Uploads\\100650\\IMG_20200107_094705_5.jpg"` (could be verified by console.log)

Then there is another escape when it is formally converted to a js object,the finally result will be `"path":"\temp\Uploads\100650\IMG_20200107_094705_5.jpg"`

So if you want one `\` in a js object, you need four `\` in a json string

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, when I serialize the object into a string it does contain the 4 \'s.  Then it is passed as a parameter from the phone app to the javascript in the webview.  If I add a breakpoint and look at the parameter before any attempt is make to parse, it only contains one \.

Comment: as i said finally，if you want two \，you should use eight \

Comment: It will escapes twice